# Найти координаты родителя

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт меню, в нем определяется положение всплывающего блока:

```
BX.adjust(this.popup, {
    style: {
        left: (offsetRightPopup - 2) + "px",
        top: this.element.offsetTop + "px"
    }
});
```

Если я правильно понял, то эта часть скрипта устанавливает стиль для всплывающего блока, где отступ `top` равен координате высоты блока, вызывающего появление.

Я же хочу, чтобы высота была равна координате родительского блока, но не знаю как этого добиться. Куда я только этот parent() не помещал...

Comment: Если `this.element` - тот DOM элемент, `.offsetTop` родителя которого нужно взять, то можно использовать `this.element.parentNode.offsetTop`

Comment: Уважаемый @Regent Ваш вариант отлично работает, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Доступ к родительскому элементу у DOM элемента осуществляется с помощью свойства `.parentNode`. Поэтому отступ сверху родительского элемента можно получить следующим образом:

```
this.element.parentNode.offsetTop
```